# Resize the carousel view during a screen orientation in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, icarousel

I have a problem with `iCarousel` view to resizing the item placed in carousel view during screen orientation changes.How can i fix this?

Here is my code

```
- ( void ) handleOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation )toInterfaceOrientation {

    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

        orient = YES;

        _deptCarousel.center = CGPointMake(390, 628);

    }else {

        orient = NO;

        _deptCarousel.center = CGPointMake(512, 455);

    }

}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{

    //create a numbered view
    UIView *viewBG = nil;
    viewBG = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IS_IPAD?@"Scroll_Placeholder_ImageiPad.png":@"Carousel_Placeholder_Image.png"]];
    if (IS_IPAD) {
        if (orient) {
            viewBG.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 420, 350);
        }else{
            viewBG.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 380, 280);
        }
    } else {
        viewBG.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 210, 170);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have checked your device orientation when the `iCarousel` loads for the first time.You have to check and resize your `Carousel` View whenever your orientation changes. So try to check it in the orientation delegate like below.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  UIInterfaceOrientation statusBarOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if (IS_IPAD) {
       if (orient) {
            viewBG.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 420, 350);
         }else{
            viewBG.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 380, 280);
         }
    }

    [_deptCarousel reloadData];

  return YES;
}
```

I think it may help you. Please let me know if you have any queries in this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

well for changing the frame you should reload your carousel in your Orientation method otherwise it won't effect it.

```
- ( void ) handleOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation )toInterfaceOrientation {

    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

        orient = YES;

        _deptCarousel.center = CGPointMake(390, 628);

        //reload your Carousel

    }else {

        orient = NO;

        _deptCarousel.center = CGPointMake(512, 455);

         //reload your Carousel


    }

}
```